# Click button show different text, repeat first text

Tags: javascript, php, html

## HTML:

```
<button id="slider1next" >Clickme</button>
  <p class="text" id="first_one">This is the first text</p>
    <p class="text" id="second_one" style="display:none">This is the second text</p>
    <p class="text" id="third_one" style="display:none">This is the third text</p>
<p class="text" id="fourth_one" style="display:none">This is the four text</p>
```

## JavaScript:

```
$("#slider1next").click(function() {
    var $next = $(".text:visible").hide().next();
    $next.length ? $next.show() : $(".text:first").show();
});

$("#slider2next").click(function() {
    var $next = $(".text:visible").hide().prev();
    $next.length ? $next.show() : $(".text:last").show();
});
```

I want to make it where the text is shown, but after the last text, it repeats the first text.

Trying to make something like [this](http://wtfhasobamadonesofar.com/1/)

If there's a better way to do this, other than using JavaScript and HTML, please let me know.. But `JavaScript` and `HTML` is the only way I can think of, an alternative to JS functions would be `jQUERY`. Help? ;-;

Looking for suggestions with the use of `PHP`, too, maybe to mock the code's intended for what I am trying to re-create using a different set of languages.

Comment: What does this have to do with php?

Comment: ^^ Perhaps PHP could be used as a better alternative?
http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10312177-PHP-to-take-action-upon-button-click

Comment: try to use id instant of class in java script

Comment: ^^ Perhaps PHP could be used as a better alternative?
http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10312177-PHP-to-take-action-upon-button-click

Just really looking for alternatives to button clicking for a different page, like maybe calling a directory of the same url to display the same css but different text upon button click?

Comment: Deepesh Kumar, how would I use the id instant? I am not a specialist in JS ;P

Comment: I created a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7w0qpkf3/ with your given code. It already works as specified in your question, cycling back to the 1st text after the 4th. What is wrong, then?

Comment: @Thernys Weird, http://jsfiddle.net/joaopsilva/gjGvn/

Comment: In case it was not obvious, your fiddle has a completely different click callback for `#slider1next` than your question. One that indeed does not work as your question specifies.

Comment: @Thernys Could you make a reply indicating this so I can mark you as the individual that totally resolved my confusion? I was curious as to why it wasn't working as indicated. Thank-you so much, Thernys. I do appreciate it.

Comment: What is your problem? It work as you want (`after the last text, it repeats the first text`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var count = 0;
$("#sliderNext").click(function() {
  count++;
  if (count < $('.text').length) {
    $(".text:nth(" + count + ")").show().prev().hide();
  } else {
    $(".text:first").show();
    $(".text:last").hide();
    count = 0;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="sliderNext">Next</button>

<p class="text" id="first_one">This is the first text</p>
<p class="text" id="second_one" style="display:none">This is the second text</p>
<p class="text" id="third_one" style="display:none">This is the third text</p>
<p class="text" id="fourth_one" style="display:none">This is the four text</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the modulo function to loop through a set of numbers: (count % 4) + 1.   This will cycle through the numbers 1,2,3, and 4 if count starts at 0 and increases with each click of the next button.

Comment: How would I go about integrating this?

Comment: `(count%4)+1` would cycle through 1, 2, 3, 4. Besides that, this does not really seem to answer the (admittedly not so great) question, except in very small part.

Comment: @Comradeo Disclaimer: I don't know JQuery. Answer: Change <p> ids to slideshow_#, with # being a number from 1-4. Increase count every time the next button is clicked. Show <p> with id = (count % 4) + 1. Hide the others.

Comment: @Feathercrown Sample?

Comment: @Thernys Not so great question?

Comment: @Comradeo Sorry, I don't know JQuery, but the logic of my idea seems sound. You could use (count % 4) + 1 in an if statement, and manually program in the showing and hiding of the <p> elements in the if statement block.